# Return one column from navigation table in my lambda linq query by .include()

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, relational-database

I use this lambda linq query to retrieve data from database as a list:

```
return _context.BaseCompanies.Where(x => x.Active)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCity)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupFour)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupOne)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupThree)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupTwo)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyTitle)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyType)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCountry)
            .Include(b => b.BaseProvince).ToList();
```

The records are 10 record but there are many relation with another table, also I want to use data from related tables, for this reason use `.include()`, but when I use `.Include()`, it returns all data from related table and with this relation return more unnecessary data from database.

For example from table `City`, I need only name of city, but return `Id`, `Name`, `CreateDate`,...

How can I retrieve only `Name` of the city from table city with include?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Select` to reshape the data:

```
return await _context.BaseCompanies.Where(x => x.Active).Select(x =>
{
    SomePropOnBaseCompany = x.SomePropOnBaseCompany,
    SomePropOnBaseCity = x.BaseCity.SomePropOnBaseCity,
    // etc.
}).ToListAsync();
```

You don't need the `Include` calls at all if you're specifically selecting props from related entities. EF will automatically issue joins to fill the data you're requesting. Just list out the properties you want to pull.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Select` to return any column and return as `List<BaseCompany>`

```
var p = _context.BaseCompanies.Select(bp => new BaseCompany
        {
            //your custom fields
            Id = bp.Id,
            Description = bp.Description,

            //for one-to-one relationship
            BaseCity = new City()
            {
                Name = bp.BaseCity.Name
            },

            //for one-to-many relationship
            BaseCity = bp.BaseCity.Select(city=> new City
            {
                Name = city.Name
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```